# Symfony LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle A Token was not found in the TokenStorage

Tags: ubuntu, symfony, php-5.5, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle working on my Symfony project and locally it works great.

The issue I am having is in the remote server. If I do a post to the end point login_check with the correct username and password I get the token without any issues but when I then try to send the token in the Authentication header to another end point I always get 401 Invalid credentials

Can any one help me out narrowing this down? My machine doesn't have the exact configurations that the server has. What might be the cause of this?

I am getting the AuthenticationException  "A Token was not found in the TokenStorage" which I don't really know what it means or how to fix it.

Again, **I have a valid token** and the same call that works perfectly locally, fails in the remote server.

Thanks!

SERVER INFO

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

Symfony version 3.0.3

lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle v1.4.3

**Note**: I have opened an issue in the [lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle github](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/148) page which offers even more detail.

**EDIT**: Sorry for wasting everyone's time. Mod_rewrite was not enabled :(

Comment: I guess the server is in prod environment and use apache or nginx as webserver, right ? Can you try to run the application trough the php built-in server ? (i.e. `app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000`) in order to see if the error occurs and remove doubt about that the webserver configuration.

Comment: @chalasr Thanks for the help but the issue was that mod rewrite was not on.